# Manage independently the decimal number of the price of each product

Tags: php, woocommerce, decimal, price

I develop an online store with woocommerce and I would like to display the price of the product with 3 decimals when the price contains 3 (example 1). But when the last number of the price is 0, I want to display only 2 decimals (example 2). Do you know how to do this please ?

I found a filter, but it affects all the prices at the same time :

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals' , 'custom_price_decimals', 20, 1 );
function custom_price_decimals( $decimals ) {
  if( is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ){
    $decimals = 3;
    return $decimals;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Example 1

[image: example 1]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/06/3/1549461179-2-925.png))</sub>

Example 2

[image: example 2]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/06/3/1549461179-4-55.png))</sub>

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow image hoster instead of noelshack.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$decimals=strlen(ltrim(($float - floor($float)),"0."));
```

It returns numbers after dot without zeros